# Understanding frequency-based probability distributions

Tags: probability, distributions

I am experimenting with various domain similarity measures across a number of language-based domains, based on their relative term frequency, but I've managed to confuse myself when it comes to creating these distributions as it's something I'm unfamiliar with.

Specifically, I am trying to reproduce an experiment where the authors define a term distribution as follows:

[image]

The authors then follow this up by stating that they limited the vocabulary size to k = 10,000.

Am I right in understanding that, if I were to create term distributions for *n* domains, I would calculate the top-k terms that are present across all distributions (so as to ensure no zero probabilities), and then divide the counts for each term across |V|?

Is |V| here equal to k, i.e. the unique top-k terms? Or is it equal to all of the occurrences of k terms across all samples?

Comment: Probably need to extract some other definitions from this text to make any sense of it. Looks like they mean $\mathbb{R}$ to mean a "vocabulary" which, I assume is a set of words and their relative frequency in, say, written text. That's some bastardization if so, cuz it's a finite set of words. $\mathbb{R}^{|V|}$ I gather means a *specific* vocabulary. For instance, the particle `a` exists in Spanish, French, and English (and probably other "vocabularies"), so the most likely language based on finding an `a` in the text is in whichever it appears *most* frequently.

Comment: My fault for not specifying. The datasets here are compared on domains of Amazon reviews, all in English. So their terms differ depending on topics, i.e. whether someone is writing about Book reviews, Movie reviews, etc. So the semantics change with respect to that. And the goal is to compare the most similar kinds of reviews across these topical domains.

Comment: That information doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: As I understand it, if I have 1000 documents from each domain, and I want to compare the distributions of top-k terms amongst those domains, I would collect the relative terms, and then compute the frequencies of them per-domain to create a k-length distribution? It is rather vague in the paper.

Comment: Yes, but you're missing something. The NLP approach takes the dictionary as fixed: an example is using Moby Dick to train the English "vocabulary" and then you compare other text to it. If you use 1,000 reviews to "train" your vocabulary, you won't have the uncertainty in estimation to perform any comparisons or inference. It sounds like what you need to do is calculate some giant Chi-square test of independence.